# My system hangs and screen becomes like the below image

Tags: windows, windows-10

My system hangs and screen becomes like the below image. It is happening multiple times and I don't know if it's screen issue, operating system issue or any hardware issue. Please help. The Operating system is windows 10.
[image]

Comment: More information is needed. When did this start happening? What changes have been made? What are the components (PC, display, GPU etc.).

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the info requested in the comment above. Also, provided you have peripherals, you can start troubleshooting by ruling out the monitor - test with a different monitor - and, to rule out software (OS), you can try a Linux live session (booting from USB or DVD) and let it run for a fair amount of time to see if the problem happens there or not.

Comment: Good chance the symptom is related to the display adapter, and a good chance that it is a driver issue rather than hardware.  Start with Karen Hu's answer and let us know whether that solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update your display driver, you'll need to start your PC in safe mode, uninstall your current display adapter, and then check for driver updates.

1. Start your PC in safe mode, then right-click the **Start** button and select **Device Manager**.
2. Expand the **Display adapters** section, right-click the listed adapter, then select **Uninstall device**. Select the **Delete the driver software for this device** check box, then select **Uninstall** and restart your PC.
3. After your PC restarts, press the **WIN+I** on your keyboard to open **Settings**. If that doesn't work, select the Start  button and then select Settings.
4. From Settings, select **Update & security > Windows Update > Check for updates**.

Reference here:https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/12374/windows-10-troubleshoot-screen-flickering

Comment: It worked..! Didn't have any problem till now. Thanks again.